# Confusion on compound interest arithmetic with Java

Tags: java, math, format

I hope this isn't a horrifically obvious question, but I'm new to Java and I've been creating a compound interest calculator.  I wan't to take all the values that the user inputs and compute them.

```
P = present value,
r = rate,
m = times compounded in a year,
t = years compounded. 
A = the amount at the end of the term
```

A is what  I'm looking for.  The formula for compound interest is

> `A = P(1+r/m)^mt`.

```
    A = Math.pow((P*(1+r/m)),m*t);
    System.out.println("The amount(A) equals "+A);
```

I feel that I may know why the computation isn't working right, but I don't know the right way.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what the inputs are and what the expected output is?

Comment: inputs are double since there could be decimals.   P = 555 r = 0.05 m = 1 t = 2 and A is the one needed to be found.  A is supposed to be $687.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
double amount,Principal ;
int r,m,t;
Amount = Principal * Math.pow( (1+(r/m)) , m*t );
System.out.println("The amount(A) equals "+amount);
```

Comment: In words, OP needed to move the multiplication by `P` outside of the `Math.pow` call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you formula is incorrect. You need to write it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = 100;
        int t = 5;
        int r = 10;
        int m = 2;
        double amount = p * Math.pow(1 + (r / m), m * t);
        double interest = amount - p;
        System.out.println("Compond Interest is " + interest);
        System.out.println("Amount is " + amount);

    }
```